# Label's text not showing 'á' (hungarian) letter

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display hungarian languge letters in a kivy app, but whenever i use `é` , `á`, `ö` or some other ones it is displayed like this (`é` -> `Ã©`)(`á` -> `Ã¡`) (`ö` -> `Ã¶`)

example:

```
ButtonF:
    id: beallit
    pos_hint: {'x': .375, 'y': .27}
    text: "Beállitások"
```

now this Button's text is displayed as: `BeÃ¡llitÃ¡sok`

I have tried changing the font to a font which supports the hungrian alphabet, even though the font of the text changed the letters still didnt show.

example:

```
ButtonF:
    id: beallit
    pos_hint: {'x':.375, 'y': .27}
    text: "Beállitások"
    font_name: 'OpenSans'
    on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current  = 'screen5'
```

Here the `Button's` text is in OpenSans font but it still doesnt diplay hungarian letters: `BeÃ¡llitÃ¡sok`

But when i write the Button's text from the python code not from the kivy rule, the text containing hungarian alphabet is shown correctly.

in py:

```
beallit_text = StringProperty()
beallit_text = 'Beállitások'
```

in kv:

```
ButtonF:
    id: beallit
    pos_hint: {'x':.375, 'y': .27}
    text: root.beallit_text
    font_name: 'OpenSans'
    on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current  = 'screen5'
```

Now i could just change all the `Label's`/`Button's` text from the py code but there are too many of them.
Is there an easier way?

Comment: Please use English. Only Hungarians will understand  eg. "beallit_text"  Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a common encoding issue in Kivy where non-UTF-8 encoding (such as chcp 1252) is being used. One way is to just find the encoded version of the text. For example, what you can do instead of this

```
ButtonF:
    text: 'Título'
```

is to use the UTF-8 encoded version of it in literal.

```
ButtonF:
    text: str(b'T\xc3\xadtulo'.decode())
```

For your case, `á -> \xc3\xa1 (in UTF-8 literal)`. You can check out the whole list [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal).

Or, you can simply identify the encoding used. Make sure your `.kv` file is saved in `UTF-8`

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
with open('MyApp.renamed.kv', encoding='utf8') as f: 
    Builder.load_string(f.read())
```

[this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4003) pointed me to the answer.

Comment: It's probably more sustainable to just use `UTF-8` files.

Comment: On a more general note, it's never wise to `open()` text files without giving the `encoding` parameter. There is no hidden magic that recognizes encodings for you, you **must** be explicit about it.. If you neglect to specify an encoding and it still works, that only means you got lucky – other people on different machines with different default values will run into bugs.